# Pytorchs' nn.Linear returns only `nan` values under certain conditions

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a `pytorch` tensor with my normalized data that at some point pass through this layer on my model,

`linear = nn.Linear(in_features=137, out_features=1)`

The data can be seen here,

[image]

[image]

The issue is that I only get `nan`s as a result

[image]

and the parameters of `linear` appear to also be `nan`,

[image]

In order to hopefully better understand what the issue was I saved the data at that exact moment into a csv file and loaded them in an interpreter,

[image]

performing the exact operation yields the expected result,

```
>>> linear(x)
tensor([[ 0.0594],
        [ 0.1051],
        [ 0.1000],
        ...,
        [ 0.1043],
        [-0.1210],
        [-0.0332]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

Where could this odd behaviour be attributed to, and how may I fix it?

Comment: can you check gradient magnitude?

Comment: @Shai how do you do that? I am also trying to trace the start of the issue and found that the parameters for linear are also `nan` before it is even applied for the example above.